# fill an array with variables with a loop

Tags: powershell

I have converted a log file to an array, some elements in array contain the keyword `Messages`. I want a new array that only contains elements with that keyword.

I tried the following:

```
$Logfile_array = Get-Content "C:\temp\logfiles\complete_log.txt"
foreach ($array_element in $Logfile_array)
{
    if ($array_element -match 'Messages')
    {
        foreach ($array_element in $Logfile_array)
        {
          $i++
          echo $i
          $array_message[$i] = $array_element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you add the first message once, the second twice and so on. Is that what you intended?

Comment: What is `$array_element` supposed to be in the inner loop, when you also use it in the outer loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `foreach` to loop through the array and then checking each item, you can use [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) to do this for you:

```
$Logfile_array = Get-Content "C:\temp\logfiles\complete_log.txt"
$array_message = $Logfile_array | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Messages' }
```

or a one liner:

```
$array_message = Get-Content "C:\temp\logfiles\complete_log.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Messages' }
```